# react native: navigation 5 - how can go back from Tab.Navigator?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, react-navigation

navigation 5 - how can go back from Tab.Navigator?
The problem is that if I'm now in a particular Tab.Navigator and then trying to go back then it continues to navigate me inside Tab.Navigator right to left then goes back and exits Tab.Navigator.
I do not understand how this situation can be prevented.
I just want that when I'm in a certain Tab.Navigator and want to go back from it then he will not navigate me inside the same Tab.Navigator but will just go back as I want it to happen.

**this is my tabs example :**

```
export default function TopTabs() {
  return (
    <Tab.Navigator
      tabBarOptions={{
        activeTintColor: 'black',
        // inactiveTintColor: 'grey',
        indicatorStyle: {
          // backgroundColor: 'red',
        },
        style: {
          // backgroundColor: '#8bb8ef',
        },
        labelStyle: {
          fontSize: 18,
          fontWeight: 'bold',
        },
      }}
    >
      <Tab.Screen
        name="bomb"
        component={ReshimatDrishotLebitzua}
      />
      <Tab.Screen name="frog" component={DrishotSheTuplu} />
    </Tab.Navigator>
  );
}
```

Comment: Try to put your Tab.Navigator inside a Stack Navigator maybe ?

Comment: are u sure ?  its not works :(